# Why does a Userlist Component show up in the browser with an ul children element when there is no such thing in the components folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm weirded out by what shows up in the browser when I run npm start in the terminal. In my dev/js/index.js file I have the following:

```
import SC from 'soundcloud';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux'
import {combineForms, createForms} from 'react-redux-form';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import allReducers from './reducers';
import App from './components/App';
import { CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI } from './constants/auth';


SC.initialize({ client_id: CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI });

const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger)
);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <div>
                <Route path="/" component={App}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Furthermore, inside of the App.js, I have the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PlaylistSearchBar from './PlaylistSearchBar';
import PossibleMatches from './PossibleMatches';
import EventTicketsSearchBar from './EventTicketsSearchBar';
import Intro from './Intro';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
   };
}

export default App;
```

What in the world is causing the browser on npm start to display this:

[image]

Inside of the console, under the React section, I have:

[image]

This is super weird to me because I literally don't have any components name UserList with shown children elements. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.